# How to limit pg_dump's memory usage?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, azure, heroku, pg-dump

I have a ~140 GB postgreDB on Heroku / AWS. I want to create a dump of this on a windows Azure - Windows server 2012 R2 virtual machine, as i need to move the DB into Azure environment.

The DB has a couple of smaller tables, but mainly consists of a single table taking ~130 GB, including indexes. It has ~500 million rows.

I've tried to use pg_dump for this, with:

```
./pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner --host * --port 5432 -U * -d * > F:/051418.dump
```

I've tried on various Azure virtual machine sizes, including some fairly large with (D12_V2) 28GB ram, 4 VCPUs 12000 MAXIOPs, etc. But in all cases the pg_dump stalls completely due to memory swapping.

On above machine it's currently using all available memory and has used the past 12 hrs swapping memory on the disk. I dont expect it to complete, due to the swapping.

From other posts i've understood it could be an issue with the network speed, beeing much faster than the disk IO speed, causing pg_dump to suck up all available memory and more, so i've tried using the azure machine with most IOPs. This hasnt helped.

So is there another way i can force pg_dump to cap it's memory usage, or wait on pulling more data until it has written to disk and clear memory ?

Looking forward to your help!

Krgds.

Christian

Comment: Maybe it is because you are using stdout redirecting, try letting pg_dump write directly to file `./pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner --host * --port 5432 -U * -d * -f F:/051418.dump`

Comment: Offcourse ;) It works like a charm!

Thank You!